# In $\mathbb{R}^n$ , are open sets not closed and closed sets not open?

Tags: general-topology

I know that it is the case for $\mathbb{R}$ and I suspect for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This is assuming the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The title holds for (proper subspaces of) $\mathbb{R}^n$, since it's connected (being, for example, path-connected).

Comment: If $X$ is a topological space which is connected, then the only subsets of $X$ which are both open and closed are $X$ and $\varnothing$. And of course, $\Bbb{R}^n$ are connected!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try the simplest examples of open sets possible.

If that doesn't satisfy you, use what you know about the metric space definition of "open" and "closed" to answer your question for all the *other* open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (as long as we exclude the trivial cases - the empty set and the whole space are both open and closed).

The spaces which have this property are exactly the **connected** ones - because if $U, V$ is a partition of $X$ into disjoint open sets, then $U$ and $V$ are each open and closed, and if $U$ is both open and closed then $X\setminus U$, $U$ is a partition into disjoint opens.